# I want to use FB.Event.subscribe to record tracking value on Facebook like button, but met one issue

Tags: javascript, facebook

The description of the issue is, if we want to add tracking function to FB & Twitter button, we have to use XFBML method to develop the FB button(please refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ), because only XFBML method is supported to use Facebook’s Api to catch the click event on facebook like button(no matter which method we use to develop the buttons, the buttons always will be put into an iframe in HTML, the elements in iframe are different domain from our site, so we are not able to control the element in iframe, Facebook & Twitter offer some Apis which can be used to develop and control the buttons, but these Apis only can be called by using XFBML method.), we try to use the Facebook api FB.Event.subscribe (please refer to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/ see the detail) to catch the click event on facebook button and enable the tracking, it worked and the tracking value can be returned successfully, but our issue is: if we use article & gallery page (article & gallery contain FB & Twitter button),also use FB & Twitter button on NetworkHeader, like this:

If we click the button on header, it will call tracking function and send tracking value, but after clicking the button on header, then click the button in article or gallery, it won’t return any tracking value, our question is: we are not able to differentiate the relative tracking value on header or article, which mean if we click the button on header, it will call FB.Event.subscribe and enable tracking function, but in the same HTML, the button on article also will run the FB.Event.subscribe, although we use independent JS file which is only for FB & Twitter button on header, we are not able to control or modify the Api from Facebook or Twitter, no matter which button(in article or on header) we click, it always will call the first JS file loaded which contains FB.Event.subscribe function, the other Facebook button in the same HTML also will run the function, that mean if we click the other FB & Twitter button in article or gallery, the tracking value is wrong, it will return header button’s tracking value.

Are you able to do me a favor if there is any way to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

I've needed to do something similar on a project I've worked on, and this is how I did it.

Firstly the XFBML implementation of Facebook's social plugins isn't the only type that will fire events - the HTML5 version will also. I'd suggest using that version as..well HTML5 is just better markup.

So, the trick here is to provide a `ref` attribute as part of your element, such as:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/" 
    data-send="false" 
    data-action="like" 
    data-layout="button_count" 
    data-width="150" 
    data-show-faces="false" 
    data-font="arial" 
    data-ref="header">
</div>
```

Then from within your `FB.Event.subscribe` function you can do the following:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(targetUrl, elm) {
    switch(elm._attr.ref) {
        case 'header':
            // tracking code
            break;

        case // ... etc
    }
});
```